# Get InstallDate from Win32_QuickFixEngineering

Tags: c#, wmi

I'm trying to get HotFixes and Updates from Win32_QuickFixEngineering, everything looks good, except that `GetPropertyValue("InstallDate")` returns `null`.

Can I somehow retrieve `InstallDate` or I should use `InstalledOn` instead?

[image]

```
public static string HotFixes()
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "Select * from Win32_QuickFixEngineering");
    foreach (ManagementObject wmi in searcher.Get())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(wmi.GetPropertyValue("Description").ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(wmi.GetPropertyValue("HotFixID").ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(wmi.GetPropertyValue("InstallDate").ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(wmi.GetPropertyValue("InstalledOn").ToString());
    }
    return "---";
}

RESULT WITHOUT "InstallDate" WILL BE
--------------
Update
KB4571756
9/9/2020
```

Comment: From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-quickfixengineering) it looks like `InstallDate` does not necessarily have a value: "Indicates when the object was installed. Lack of a value does not indicate that the object is not installed."

Comment: If you post your comment as answer I will check it as correct answer because you were totally right about what you said. I just did not listen back than but after doing silly things  I followed to your comment and just put check if it's not empty show the date or show "unknown". Thank you